# What is Qui-Gon Jinn saying to Anakin by waving his hand like this?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

> Jinn: I must speak with the Jedi Council immediately. The situation
> has become much more complicated.
>
> (Anakin stops following Padme and turns back)
>
> Padme: Ani, come on.
>
> Jinn and Anakin wave hands to each other:

[image: Anakin, following the handmaids, looks back questioningly. Qui-Gon gestures encouragingly. Anakin turns and continues.]

What is Qui-Gon Jinn telling to Anakin by waving his hand like this?

Comment: That way? Yes, that way.

Comment: I interpreted it as " Yes, go with them"

Comment: The more interesting questions would be, is there any sensible interpretation other than "go with them"?

Comment: It looked like an annoyed "Don't ask, just obey" to me, out of context.

Comment: To me, that gesture says, "Go on" or "Go ahead".

Comment: Can you please upload that gif to the site instead of hotlinking it? The ibb.co URL is not working for me.

Comment: Without the index finger, it might come across as dismissive (“shoo, go away, run along now”) But I think this gesture is well crafted: the hand encourages to go; the finger indicates “there/with them” (not just “away”); the slight head nod reassures: “it’s ok, go with them”.

Comment: I thought he was using the force to turn Anakin around

Comment: I think it is too easy to read too much into it.

Comment: @Valorum This is the way.

Comment: @TylerH I tried generating thumbnails using Media Player Classic. It looks understandable for me, but I was unsure if it warrants an edit: https://www.aht.li/3566778/thumbs20201201085247.jpg

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That is a common gesture in American (U.S.) culture to, in this context, "move along".

Jinn is basically responding to Anakin's insecurity (being left off with people he doesn't know) to say something like "go on, you'll be fine".

https://www.google.com/search?q=shoo+gesture+gif&tbm=isch

Comment: Pointing could also mean "stay here".

Comment: And yes, it is not always understood the same way in other cultures.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that Qui-Gon Jinn isn't an American.

Comment: @Valorum and he doesn't speak English either.  Translation Convention applies to hand gestures as well as spoken language.

Comment: What are some real life counterexamples to the US interpretation?  What are some examples of places that don't even have an interpretation/meaning for this gesture?

Comment: @Panzercrisis That would be a different question. But, just off the top of my head, in Japan wagging ones hand (or even just curling the fingers with the hand out) means "come here".

Comment: @Panzercrisis That hand gesture has no meaning for me. I just "happen" to have seen someone using hands to say "come here", "go there" or "get away", somewhere, some time in my life, so I was "somewhat able" to second-guess that it means what it means. Pretty much like icons on websites and mobile apps, sometimes I have no idea what they mean if I didn't see them beforehand.

Answer (score 25):

In the [original script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html) (and both sets of novelisations), Jinn is '*nodding [for Anakin] to go ahead*'. I assume the hand gestures have much the same meaning.

> JAR JAR and ANAKIN start to follow, then stop, noticing that OBI-WAN and
> QUI-GON are staying with the SUPREME CHANCELLOR. QUEEN AMIDALA waves to the
> duo to follow her. **ANAKIN looks back to QUI-GON, and he nods to go ahead.**
> ANAKIN and JAR JAR join the QUEEN, PALPATINE, PADME, RABE and EIRTAE in the
> taxi. PALPATINE gives the Gungan and the boy in the back of the taxi a
> skeptical look. JAR JAR leans over to ANAKIN.

and

> Then, to Obi-Wan’s surprise, the Queen waved at Anakin and Jar Jar to join her. He was about to stop them, when he saw Qui-Gon nod to Anakin. He arranged this with her before we landed, Obi-Wan realized.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Phantom Menace: Junior Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> Anakin started to follow, Jar Jar at his side, then stopped as he saw
> that the Jedi were still standing with Supreme Chancellor Valorum.
> Anakin glanced back questioningly at Qui-Gon, not certain where he was
> supposed to go. **The Queen and her retinue slowed in response, and
> Amidala motioned for Anakin and the Gungan to join them. Anakin looked
> again at Qui-Gon, who nodded wordlessly.**
>
> <sub><sup>[The Phantom Menace: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_The_Phantom_Menace_(novelization))</sup></sub>

It's not really clear why this was changed on the day, but probably the director felt that a nod was too subtle a gesture whereas pointing is pretty clear (e.g. "you go that way").